# How to parse multidimensional JSON to html easily?

Tags: jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I want to parse json to html easily. I have a multidimensional json. so i want to parse this to html easily. any plugin or any simple code is available ? 
The following my json file.

```
    [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Delhi",
                    "capital": "New Delhi"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tamilnadu",
                    "capital": "Chennai"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Alabama",
                    "capital": "Montgomery"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Alaska",
                    "capital": "Juneau"
                }
            ]
}
]
```

The html is like this.

```
<ul>
        <li>India</li>
 <ul>
        <li>State1 :capital</li>
        <li>State2 :capita2</li>

</ul>
        <li>USA</li>
 <ul>
        <li>State1 :capital</li>
        <li>State2 :capita2</li>

</ul>

</ul>
```

I want to get output like this
Which is best and simplest way to get this output?

Comment: It should be generic for another json format or just this one ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use jquery jput plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/jput/)

http://jsfiddle.net/mse255ko/1/

```js
var data=[
        {
            "country": "India",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Delhi",
                    "capital": "New Delhi"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tamilnadu",
                    "capital": "Chennai"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Alabama",
                    "capital": "Montgomery"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Alaska",
                    "capital": "Juneau"
                }
            ]
}
];

$(document).ready(function(){
 //loading json data initally 
 $('#maindiv').jPut({
  jsonData:data,
  name:'template1'
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://shabeer-ali-m.github.io/jPut/js/jput.min.js"></script>
<div id="maindiv">
    <div jput="template1">
    <ul>
        <li>{{country}}</li>
        <ul>
            <li>State 1 Name : {{state.0.name}}, Capital : {{state.0.capital}}</li>
             <li>State 2 Name : {{state.1.name}}, Capital : {{state.1.capital}}</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: you need a forEach loop...this isn't exactly the best asnwer

Comment: @vsync if we are using plugin what is use of foreach loop

Answer (score 5):

Please use jquery each for looping the JSON data, here during each iteration the variable html value is concatenated, so you can append to any DIV.

```js
var data =    [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Delhi",
                    "capital": "New Delhi"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tamilnadu",
                    "capital": "Chennai"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Alabama",
                    "capital": "Montgomery"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Alaska",
                    "capital": "Juneau"
                }
            ]
}
];
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                       
var html = "";
    jQuery.each(data, function(i,v){
      var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v)); 
      html += "<ul><li>"+temp.country+"</li></ul>"; 
      jQuery.each(temp.state, function(j,val){ 
         html += "<li>" + val.name +"</li>"; 
      }); 
    });
    $("#result-div").html(html);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

1- Iterate arrays with `forEach`
2- check the existence of keys in dictionaries using `object.hasOwnProperty`
3- create html elements with `$("< type-of-element >")`
4- build string in desired format. 
 You can try this script:

```
var data= [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Delhi",
                    "capital": "New Delhi"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tamilnadu",
                    "capital": "Chennai"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Alabama",
                    "capital": "Montgomery"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Alaska",
                    "capital": "Juneau"
                }
            ]
    }
]

var to_append = $("body") //your append selector
if(data && data.length>0){
    var outer_ul = $("<ul>")
    data.forEach(function(e,i){
        if(e.hasOwnProperty("country")){
            outer_ul.append($("<li>", {text : e['country']}))
        }

        if(e.hasOwnProperty("state")){
            var inner_ul = $("<ul>")
            e['state'].forEach(function(__e,__i){
                if(__e.hasOwnProperty('capital')){
                    inner_ul.append($("<li>", {text : "State "+(__i+1) + " : " + __e['capital']}))
                }
            })
            outer_ul.append(inner_ul)
        }


    })
    to_append.append(outer_ul)
}
```

this will get the html output:

```
<ul>
<li>India</li>
<ul><li>State 1 : New Delhi</li><li>State 2 : Chennai</li></ul>
<li>USA</li>
<ul><li>State 1 : Montgomery</li><li>State 2 : Juneau</li></ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: this one is a great stand alone example.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery version of this problem (live sample):

- [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over array
- [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to add a child to a parent
- [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to set text content of an element

```js
var countries = [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Delhi",
                    "capital": "New Delhi"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tamilnadu",
                    "capital": "Chennai"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Alabama",
                    "capital": "Montgomery"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Alaska",
                    "capital": "Juneau"
                }
            ]
        }
]

var $root = $("ul");

$.each(countries, function () {
  $("<li>").appendTo($root).text(this.country);
  var $ul = $("<ul>").appendTo($("<li>").appendTo($root));
  $.each(this.state, function () {
    $("<li>").appendTo($ul).text(this.name + ": " + this.capital);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can also use AngularJS for this, it's one of the main points of angular that it's very easy to bind data.

```js
var data=[
        {
            "country": "India",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Delhi",
                    "capital": "New Delhi"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Tamilnadu",
                    "capital": "Chennai"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "state": [
                {
                    "name": "Alabama",
                    "capital": "Montgomery"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Alaska",
                    "capital": "Juneau"
                }
            ]
}];

function bindData($scope)
{
    $scope.countries = data;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="bindData">
<ul ng-repeat="c in countries">
 <li>{{c.country}}</li>
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="s in c.state">{{s.name}} :{{s.capital}}</li>
 </ul>
</ul>
</div>
```