# Javascript or jQuery way to display random-level JSON as HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to parse and display arbitrary-level JSON snippets as HTML. By arbitrary-level I mean there is no pre-definied structure. For example:

```
"CustomFields": [
                {
                    "Main": [
                        {
                            "None": [
                                {
                                    "SDOM Date": "2014-12-24"
                                },
                                {
                                    "User Defined 31": "2009-03-02"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Contract Data": [
                                {
                                    "Status2": "Active"
                                },
                                {
                                    "User Defined 112": "N"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Besides the CustomFields root element, everything under it is unpreditable. But basically there are layers of objects which are each an array of other objects, until you finally arrive at an object value. In the example above there are 4 levels. But there can be any number of them.

What I'd like is to display something like:

- Main

  - None

    - SDOM Date: 2014-12-24
    - User Defined 31: 2009-03-02
  - Contract Data

    - Status2: Active
    - User Defined 112: N

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse multidimensional JSON to html easily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031010/how-to-parse-multidimensional-json-to-html-easily)

Comment: I believe I saw that question, and if I'm not mistaken, while it's also multi-level, it has a pre-defined structure and a known number of levels of data.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/2055998) helps.

Comment: @PM77-1's link is more along the lines of what I was looking for. In my opinion, this is not a duplicate of the question mentioned by Mik378.

Comment: I believe you are looking for the word "[arbitrary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arbitrary)", not "[random](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/random)".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```js
var json = {"CustomFields": [
                {
                    "Main": [
                        {
                            "None": [
                                {
                                    "SDOM Date": "2014-12-24"
                                },
                                {
                                    "User Defined 31": "2009-03-02"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "Contract Data": [
                                {
                                    "Status2": "Active"
                                },
                                {
                                    "User Defined 112": "N"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }]};

function jsonToHtml(array){
    var html = '<ul>';
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (typeof array[i] == 'object'){
            for (var j in array[i]){
                var innerHTML = (typeof array[i][j]=='object')?jsonToHtml(array[i][j]):' : '+array[i][j];
                html += '<li>'+j+innerHTML+'</li>';
            }
        }
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    return html;
}
    
aaa.innerHTML = jsonToHtml(json.CustomFields);
```

```html
<div id="aaa"></div>
```

Comment: beats me... All I can offer is my `+1`.

Comment: **render()** may not be the best choice for function name. But it does work for what I need. Thanks.