# How to fetch JSON array with dynamic data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I'm currently working on university project, creating currency converter. I would like to implement history page, where I can use JSON from exchangeratesapi.io API response and display it in a table on PHP page.

For example: https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2019-04-22&end_at=2019-04-25&base=EUR&symbols=USD

```
{"base":"EUR","rates":{"2019-04-23":{"USD":1.1245},"2019-04-24":{"USD":1.1209},"2019-04-25":{"USD":1.1123}},"end_at":"2019-04-25","start_at":"2019-04-22"}
```

The problem is that the desired values are stored in an "rates" array, in which all values are changed dynamically (date and exchange rate itself) and I can not fetch and display them through the document.getElementById("").innerHTML in Javascript.

How can I fetch data from such an array into a table in HTML?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031010/how-to-parse-multidimensional-json-to-html-easily

Comment: rates is an object not array.

Comment: @BJohn but how can I link to date and rate itself? They don't have any naming, as it is in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through data and list items as below:

```
for (var key in data.rates) {
    console.log('Date: '+ key);
    console.log('Rate: '+ data.rates[key]['USD']);
}
```

[Check sample code here:](https://jsfiddle.net/fm8ktybz/)